# Having Issues while installing Ubuntu using Windows XP

Tags: installation, wubi

dear Ubuntu Community,

I have come across a strange problem while installing Ubuntu 12.04LTS version using Wubi on my desktop having Windows XP. There are four partition available in my desktop and i have used G: drive to install Ubuntu. Everytime, i use Wubi to install and it downloads the Ubuntu file and then extracts the files. However, it get stuck at the last minute of installation due to some temp folder issue. it always displays disk size issue and resizing error. for. e.g. when i tried 10G space, it got stuck at resizing disk space of 9744GB. The total space is 15GB available for UBUNTU 12.04.

Please guide me on the fix available for this issue as i have attempted trice to install and failed miserably.

---

Thanks for responding. However, i am facing a strange issue of not having it installed at all. At the time of installing UBUNTU using Wubi, it halts at the time of setup and shows some kind of error related temporary memory issue.

I have taken snapshot and read the error log file but it was quite difficult for me to interpret and fix the issue.

For anyone's understanding, i can share / upload all screen shots and log file for correlation and offering me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is buggy and it run slower than native installed Ubuntu.

Instead install Ubuntu as dual-boot with Windows.